# How to monitor my custom logs in Linux?

Tags: linux, logging

I have an application in Linux which will log if there is any error in some particular format.

Is there any log-analysis or log-monitoring software in Linux which I can configure
it according to my log format so that in case of an error it will send me a alert ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to use [syslog-ng](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/opensource-logging-system/overview) (it's available for example in Debian, Ubuntu and Gentoo repositories, for RHEL there are downloads on syslog-ng homepage).

syslog-ng allows *very* flexible syslogging. In your case I would make it match for those errors and make that syslog-ng chain to send out an e-mail / log error to database / send out an SMS or whatever alert mechanism you use.

As a bonus that would be real-time alerting.

Comment: I *love* syslog-ng (it's the syslog daemon I use everywhere, given the choice, and I've been a happy user for over a decade now), but I wouldn't use it to do the actual monitoring.  I'd have all the logs coming in to syslog-ng intially, yes, but then I'd dump them to a database or external file for the actual processing.  That gives you a lot more flexibility, and the decoupling can improve performance, too.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple, standalone solution, [swatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swatch/) is designed to attach to the end of a logfile, watch for new lines, and act on them (send email, run scripts ,etc.) depending on the content of those new lines.

Comment: I've used swatch regularly in the past.  If you need large scale log monitoring and analysis for a whole system, or for dozens of applications, swatch might not be a perfect choice.  But, for keeping an eye on a few logs and looking for a handful of specific cases, it works great.